I cannot change the plymouth theme
When i run sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth and select either the custom vortex-ubuntu theme I installed or the default ubuntu-logo theme it just uses the ubuntu-text theme. I run sudo update-initramfs -u -k all every time I try any command.  I've looked at many help forums and nothing has worked I'm completely lot right now.
I run Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
